# Getting 'User does not have Permission to access this object. Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403' error. Please see details

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to download some images from FirebaseStorage.

Though I am authenticating user through google, I'm still getting this 
error:

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. User does not have permission to access this object. Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
```

when trying to download the images.

Here's the rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/appname-e3a12.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Has anybody got answer for this?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/appname-e3a12.appspot.com/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where am I supposed to insert this: `appname-e3a12.appspot.com`?

Comment: No! Even this rules are giving the same error: `E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. User does not have permission to access this object. Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403`

Comment: I am also a beginner. I know no more.Why are not authenticating ? If you don't want to then try 


[Firebase Anonymous Login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth)

Comment: it stills gives me the same error my logCat  `StorageException has occurred.
                                                                             User does not have permission to access this object.
                                                                              Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403`

Comment: This worked for me. The other solutions did not.

Answer (score 1):

Your rules looks fine, but if you are not sure, try putting `allow read, write: if true;` to the root of your rules.

I had the same problem, I don't know which platform are you trying access Firebase Storage from, but check the referencing style in your code. Storage is different from Database. 
For example in Android, you should access a file like this:

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference().child("folderName/file.jpg");
```

Not like this:

```
 StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference().child("folderName").child("file.jpg");
```

You should also read this blog post from David East: [5 tips for Firebase Storage](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/5-tips-for-firebase-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, it is not enough to allow read/write, also you should enable Anonymous account under Firebase Console/Authentication/SIGN0IN METHOD tab, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the default rules for Firebase?

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/<your-firebase-storage-bucket>/o {
       match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
       }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Update the database rule to this :

```
service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
           allow read, write;
        }
       }
    }
```

Simply erase this part : `if request.auth == null`

Comment: The database rule posted by the OP does not include `if request.auth == null` – where would they remove it from?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer hoping it will help someone, in Firebase:

1. go to "Storage"
2. Select "Rules" tab and edit rules as per below:

   ```
   service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          // Allow access by all users
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Note: make sure you have it exactly as above, do not replace {bucket} for your project name.

Happy coding!